# Run Validation Item on Save in Experience Editor

Tags: experience-editor, validation

I have created a `custom Rule` in `/sitecore/system/Settings/Validation Rules/Item Rules`
When I press the validate button, I can see the Rule and its result, so far so good. But the `Validation Button` is optional, editors might just not use it.
What I want is to run my rule when I save the Page in `Experience Editor` and prevent saving the item like this:

[image]

I know this works fine when I add a `regex` validation on any items field template, but not sure how to deal with a validation item.

If the Validation Item is not correct, then simply asked how can I perform any action in code while saving and show this red layer if it fails?

Comment: Same issue here, were you able to find a solution?